# Firefox Inspector manually "use in console"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a bot for a website, basically just to learn about using scripts in Firefox. So I started by opening up the console and just trying out.

I now what to press a button, but the only way I can figure it out is by rightclicking and selecting "Use in console". This generates me a variable with the name tempX, but I obviously can't to that in scripts :

```
<div class="btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn3">Click here</button>
</div>
```

This is the code I see when I right click on the button and choose "Inspect Element".

Comment: What's your question?  Are you just trying to get an element as a variable?  You'll need to use `document.getElementById` or other DOM methods to get your element.

Comment: Yes. I already tried document.getElementByClassName("btn").click() but it can't find the method .click. With "use in console" it can. I checked and document.getElementByClassName("btn") is the button i want.

Comment: That's because the method is `getElementsByClassName`  (notice the `s`).  It returns a `NodeList`, that is a list of elements - even if there is only one.  Also because `btn` is the `<div>`, not the `<button>`.

Comment: What is `tempX`? What do you want to do, open the console automatically? Are you writing a Firefox add-on?

Comment: No sorry for not explaining everything correctly, i just wanted to ask the question real quick. Ok: I just want to write a javascript that automatically clicks that button (more information is not needed). Because getElementsByClassName("btn") doesn't work as Rocket Hazmat said, i do not know how to click the button without manually rightclicking the <button> and clicking "use in console". I hope that cleared some things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get element by `className` using `.` selector with `querySelector()` :

```
var my_btn = document.querySelector('.btn3');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn3').click();

console.log(document.querySelector('.btn3').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <button type="submit" class="btn3" onclick='alert("clicked!")'>Click here</button>
</div>
```